# Uniqueness of an analytic function $f: B_1(0) \longrightarrow B_1(0)$ such that $f(0) = 1/2$ and $f'(0) = 3/4$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

I've been trying to verify this for awhile now, and I can't figure out how to proceed.

I know to use the Schwarz-pick lemma to prove that the map $f(z) = \frac{z+\frac{1}{2}}{1+\frac{z}{2}}$ is such a function without issue.  My problem is that I need to show this is either the unique analytic function that does this, or that it isn't.

It IS the unique analytic *bijective* (from the unit ball to the unit ball) function that satisfies this by the lemma, but this doesn't verify that there doesn't exist some potentially non-bijective $h: B_1(0) \longrightarrow B_1(0)$ such that $h(0) = 1/2$ and $h'(0) = 3/4$.

I've tried applying the Schwarz lemma to $\frac{f-h}{2}$ for $h$ any analytic function satisfying these conditions, but can only verify that $|f(z)-h(z)| \leq 2|z|$ for all $z$, and I would need to still find a $z_0 \neq 0$ where $|f(z_0)-h(z_0)| = 2|z_0|$ to force uniqueness.

I also tried using the max-modulus principle on the same function, along with the open mapping theorem.  Essentially, I've tried assuming that $f-h$ is non-constant to try and get a contradiction from any of these theorems, but to no avail.

If anyone does have a solution, I would really appreciate a *hint*.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think it would be unique just by f(0)=1/2 and f′(0)=3/4 because h = 1/2+3/4z also satisfies your requirement, unless I missed something.

Comment: @FrozerClark |h(0.9)| > 1 so h doesn't map B_1(0) into B_1(0).

Comment: a basic idea from algebra: when you know an inverse exists, try using it.  In this case, you'd want to try $f^{-1}\circ h$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $g:B_1(0)\to B_1(0)$ be the analytic map taking $\frac{1}{2}$ to $0$ defined by $$g(z)=\frac{z-\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{z}{2}}$$ Consider $g\circ f$.

**Solution:**

> Composing, we have
>  $$(g\circ f)(z)=\frac{f(z)-\frac{1}{2}}{1-\frac{f(z)}{2}}$$
>  $$\text{ and }$$
>  $$(g\circ f)'(z) = \frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{f(z)}{2}\right)^2}f'(z)$$
>  so that $(g\circ f)'(0)=1$.
>  By the Schwarz-Pick lemma, $(g\circ f)(z)=\lambda z$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ with $|\lambda|=1$. Since $(g\circ f)'(0) = 1 = \lambda$, then $\lambda = 1$ and you can solve for $f(z)$ as $$f(z)=\frac{z+\frac{1}{2}}{1+\frac{z}{2}}$$
>  In general, for $\alpha\in B_1(0)$, $f(z)=\frac{z+\alpha}{1+\overline{\alpha}z}$ is the unique analytic map on the unit disk with $f(0)=\alpha$ and $f'(0)=1-|\alpha|^2$ by using a similar argument.